# Visual Studio 2013 - Using CASE statements query results as parameter values

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql

For one of my parameters, I am using the query results of a dataset named NetSales which uses a CASE statement (below) to populate parameter values, "NetSalesRange".  However, when selecting a value (ie. 500, 600, 700, etc.), the report provides all results, not the value selected.  When I say all results, I mean all results that meet the WHERE condition. This is correct, but I only want results of the WHERE condition and narrowed down to the "NetSalesRange" that was selected for the condition.  This is to allow the user to select and view net sales within a selected range, ie. $500 (will include $500-$599), $600 (will include $600-$699), $700 (will include $700-$799), etc.

```
SELECT 
NetSalesRange, count(*) Total
from(select
CASE 
WHEN [NetSales] * - 1 < 300 THEN '< 300' 
WHEN [NetSales] * - 1 >= 300 AND [NetSales] * - 1 <= 399.99 THEN '300' 
WHEN [NetSales] * - 1 >= 400 AND [NetSales] * - 1 <= 499.99 THEN '400' 
WHEN [NetSales] * - 1 >= 500 AND [NetSales] * - 1 <= 599.99 THEN '500' 
WHEN [NetSales] * - 1 >= 600 AND [NetSales] * - 1 <= 699.99 THEN '600' 
WHEN [NetSales] * - 1 >= 700 AND [NetSales] * - 1 <= 799.99 THEN '700' 
WHEN [NetSales] * - 1 >= 800 AND [NetSales] * - 1 <= 899.99 THEN '800' 
WHEN [NetSales] * - 1 >= 900 AND [NetSales] * - 1 <= 999.99 THEN '900' 
ELSE '> 1000' 
END AS NetSalesRange
FROM CompanyDW.Customer AS b INNER JOIN
     CompanyDW.Payments AS p ON b.OrderID = p.OrderID AND 
     p.PaymentTypeID IN ('CA', 'CK', 'CC') 
         INNER JOIN CompanyDW.Store AS s ON b.StoreID = s.StoreID 
WHERE (b.Voided IN ('NS', 'NT')) AND 
     (b.Trans IN ('53', '64', '76')) AND (NOT (b.Status = 'V')) AND
 (CAST(b.TransDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @Startdate and @Enddate) AND 
(b.NetSales * - 1 >= 500)
) d
GROUP BY NetSalesRange
ORDER BY NetSalesRange
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would adapt the SQL statement to only select the required rows in the where statement, but you could start with putting the whole SQL statement inside an outer statement and filter there:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM
 ( your sql ) AS i
 WHERE i.NetSalesRange = @Range
```

Remove the order by in the inner statement.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.